# Azure Function App - gives me the user logged

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I need to create a simple Azure Function App that gives me the username who access it.

I have enabled Azure Active Directory "Authentication/Authorization" and when I access the function URL it prompts for the user and I can login well

In Function App log I want to see the user who have logged. How can I do it?

Comment: Look at the `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME` HTTP request header. Your application can also obtain additional details on the authenticated user by calling `/.auth/me`. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Service passes user claims to your application by using special headers. External requests aren't allowed to set these headers, so they are present only if set by App Service.

You could use [`X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims) as http resquest header to get the username.

```
var name1=httpRequest.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"].ToString();
```

Also, you can retrieve the authenticated user information from the [`ClaimsPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2) instance injected in the Run method

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest httpRequest, 
    ILogger logger, 
    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{   
    var name1=httpRequest.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"].ToString();
    var name2 = claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name;
}
```

**Note**:

When you add App registrations in Azure ad, add [redirect url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-your-app-service-app) as `https://yourfunctionname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback` and click `ID token` when you setting `Advanced settings`.