# Search on INFO level Azure Function Logs

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Taking cue from here -

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63125857/azure-function-container-audit/63131294#63131294
```

I am logging which user accessed which file and at what time.
I see that it is now working fine.

Now I want to search that log message to identify a given filename was accessed by which user(s) ?
Is this feasible? Is there any Splunk like mechanism I could use.
I tried using Application Insights but it doesn't search on INFO message or may be I am not doing it correctly.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it ..In App Insights

```
union traces
| union exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where message like "<filename>"
| order by timestamp desc
```